# How to load different plugins in Play framework unit tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, playframework

I have different plugins implemented the `Plugin` interface. Now I have them hard-coded in play.plugins like this:

```
100:test.A
200:test.B
```

However in my unit tests I don't want both of them to be loaded at one time. In other words, in test A I want to load only plugin A and in test B load B only. Instead of changing the configuration file manually, is there a way to change it programmatically? I guess when `fakeApplication()` is invoked all plugins are loaded by default.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can start a `FakeApplication` with added or excluded plugins and also with custom configuration.

Here is an example in scala (I believe the Java API has an equivalent mechanism) :

```
val app = FakeApplication(  
  withoutPlugins = List("test.A", "test.B"),  
  additionalPlugins = List("test.C"),  
  additionalConfiguration = Map("customConfigKey" -> "customConfigValue")  
)
```

In Java, you can use one of the `fakeApplication` static methods available in the `play.test.Helpers` class. Here is the equivalent of the scala example :

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.List;
import play.test.FakeApplication;
import static play.test.Helpers.*;

Map<String, Object> additionalConfiguration = new HashMap<String, Object>();
additionalConfiguration.put("customConfigKey", "customConfigValue");
List<String> withoutPlugins = Arrays.asList("test.A", "test.B");
List<String> additionalPlugins = Arrays.asList("test.C");

FakeApplication app = fakeApplication(additionalConfiguration, additionalPlugins, withoutPlugins);
```

Comment: I would be nice to have also version for Java

Comment: @FrEaKmAn I've just added the equivalent example for Java.